# Using an _sql_constraints in Odoo 12 date

Tags: sql, python-3.x, odoo-12

Hi I created the following model:

```
class PrescriptionsPrescriptions(models.Model):
  _name = 'prescriptions.prescriptions'
  name = fields.Many2one('res.users','Name', default=lambda self: self.env.user, readonly=True)
  Date_entered = fields.Date(string='Date', default=fields.Date.today())
  paper_prescriptions = fields.Selection([('yes', 'Yes'), ('no', 'No')], string='Paper Prescriptions?')
```

However I cannot get the _sql_constraints to work:

```
_sql_constraints = [('log_unique','unique(name,Date_entered)','You have already logged data for that date.')]
```

I'm trying to get it so that each person can log only one prescription per Date_entered. Would greatly appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo will not be able to add the constraint because of a `psycopg2.ProgrammingError`

> > column "date_entered" named in key does not exist

You just need to rename it to `date_entered` and update the module.

Answer (score 0):

First you can’t have capital letters as starting of your variable. 
Second the only reason constraints don’t work after updating is when there is already data violating the constraints